# Dim screen with transparent black image

Tags: display, screen, brightness

The LCD backlighting of my notebook's screen uses [PWM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pulse-width_modulation) to dim the display, and because of this, I experience eye-strain whenever I lower the brightness. Maximum brightness however seems too much in most cases.

To solve this problem, I use [PangoBright](http://www.pangobright.com/) on Windows which does not actually dim the screen but it puts a transparent black image on top of everything and I can choose how transparent it should be. This way I can make my screen darker but keep the actual brightness at 100% to eliminate flickering.

I would like to ask if there are any softwares like this for Ubuntu. I have only found regular screen brightness changers so far. Thank you very much in advance.

Here is some more info about PWM from Wikipedia:
*"As of 2012, most implementations of LCD backlighting use PWM to dim the display, which makes the screen flicker more acutely (this does not mean visibly) than a CRT monitor at 85 Hz refresh rate would (this is because the entire screen is strobing on and off rather than a CRT's phosphor sustained dot which continually scans across the display, leaving some part of the display always lit), causing severe eye-strain for some people. Unfortunately, many of these people don't know that their eye-strain is being caused by the invisible strobe effect of PWM. This problem is worse on many of the new LED backlit monitors, because the LEDs have a faster turn-on/turn-off time than a CCFL lamp."*